# Embedding Spredsheet (Using SpreadsheerGear) in Web Page

Tags: asp.net, spreadsheetgear

I want to Embed Spreadsheets in my Web Page. Using Windows its OK but how i will do same thing in Web page.

I gone through ASP.NET Samples from [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/asp.net.aspx) but sample tells that to download Excel sheet on client side. But there is possibility that Microsoft Office is not installed on client machine. Some of Example tells to make dataset from Excel and shows Spreadheets Contents in DataGrid.

How i can directly show Embedded Spreadsheet on Web Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SpreadsheetGear 2012 for .NET* does not offer interactive web-based UI controls similar to the WinForms and WPF WorkbookView and FormulaBar controls offered in this product.

The *SpreadsheetGear 2012 for Silverlight* product, however, is intended to work in a Silverlight Application (which could be hosted within an ASP.NET website) and does include WorkbookView and FormulaBar controls to present a rich, Excel-like experience to the end-user within the browser.  If developing and deploying a Silverlight Application is a viable option for you and your clients, I'd recommend taking a closer look at this product.  You can find live samples of this Silverlight product from the following link:

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/silverlight.aspx

Comment: Thanks For answer. As my target is to show spreadsheets web page. I already done my project in Windows Forms. Sorry, i am not familiar with silverlight so much but is it necessary to install Silverlight plug-in on client side if i used silverlight application within asp.net webpage. Whether i open that Webpage on any device PC/Smart Phones/Ipad's.